# Virtual Memory Map Windows

Tags: windows, api, memory, dictionary, virtual

I was looking for API functions that returns information about the virtual memory of a process to create a map like VMMap does.

[image: VMMap]

I looked through debugging, process info and memory management functions though did not find anything useful.

Comment: If it was that easy then anybody could do this.  Mark Russinovich is famous for writing code that dynamically installs a device driver so he can poke at undocumented internal kernel data structures.  He does not share his secrets.

Comment: Third party applications like OllyDbg, a 32bit debugger, does this as well so there must be a way.

Comment: Hmya, you need to be specific about what features you *need*.  Don't say "everything".

Comment: I needed one or more functions that allow me to create a virtual memory map of a process with information of the allocated regions like access rights or size. VirtualQueryEx does this. I must have missed that function in the reference somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The [VirtualQueryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function does exactly what I wanted.